# SQL Server 2016 Convert function with null date type is different from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I am facing an issue regarding SQL Server built-in function `CONVERT`.

After the migration from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2016, there is one difference found on this migration.

I have go through the `CONVERT` function from latest MS Doc, it will return null when the datatype parameter provided is null. I wonder why SQL Server 2008 R2 is working fine....

In SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE(), NULL)
```

returns a date value.

In SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE(), NULL)
```

returns `NULL`.

PS: returning `NULL` is the correct behavior, but I wonder why the earlier versions returned a date value.

Comment: FWIW, this behavior has always been a bug, that's now been fixed. In SQL Server 2005 Books Online it's already documented that the result should be `NULL` if the third parameter is `NULL` -- the engine just never actually did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legacy behavior of this breaking change can be controlled by the database compatibility level. Compatibility level 100 (SQL Server 2008) will return a non-null value.

As to why, it seems Microsoft determined `NULL` is correct value to return with a `NULL` style and changed the behavior accordingly. The older database compatibility level provides a way to avoid breaking code until it can be remediated.